# How to convert list of string dates to datetime in python

Tags: python, list, datetime

I'm trying to convert each element of this list of strings to DateTime. I've extracted these dates from a 'log' file. This list has 1127655 elements like following:

```
01/Aug/1995:00:00:01 
01/Aug/1995:00:00:07 
01/Aug/1995:00:00:08 
01/Aug/1995:00:00:08 
01/Aug/1995:00:00:08 
01/Aug/1995:00:00:09
```

I am trying to convert this list into following format:

```
1995-08-01 00:00:09
```

I tried using this code for a list of 3 elements:

```
for item in newdate:
    print(item)
    read = datetime.datetime.strptime(item,'%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
    print(read)
```

It works fine for a couple of elements, but not for the whole list. I am getting this error constantly:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Can anyone explain what this error is and why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Which line(s) is it failing on? You should `.strip()` every line to remove new line characters

Comment: `newdate` is not defined. You need to provide a [mre].

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm not able to understand which line its failing on. Where should I use `.strip() ` ?

Comment: @wjandrea actually I just created a newdate list containing 3 elements to check whether the code is working or not. It's working for a lower amount of list size.

Comment: one of the dates is not the same format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an "unconverted data remains" when you pass a date_string different(i.e extra content at the end) from the conversion format. Example, the below will throw an error

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("01/Aug/1995:00:00:01+0030", "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")
```

To avoid this, and also other error cases like passing "01 /Aug/1995:00:00:01" etc, use the below before converting it to date.

```
item = re.sub("\s", "", item)
item = item[0:20]
# in one line item = re.sub("\s", "", item)[0:20]
```

Answer (score 1):

I approached it through [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library

Here is what I have got:

```py
from datetime import datetime

# Reproducing your file

file = """01/Aug/1995:00:00:01
01/Aug/1995:00:00:07
01/Aug/1995:00:00:08
01/Aug/1995:00:00:08
01/Aug/1995:00:00:08
01/Aug/1995:00:00:09"""

# First, split all lines using `\n`
parsed_dates = file.split("\n") #now your dates are in the form of a python list

# Convert your strings to datetime, using `datetime` library
dates = [datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S") for date in parsed_dates]

# Convert your datetimes to strings in the desired format
converted_dates = [str(date) for date in dates] # Year-Month-Day HH:MM:SS is the default output for stringfied dates

# Result:
['1995-08-01 00:00:01',
 '1995-08-01 00:00:07',
 '1995-08-01 00:00:08',
 '1995-08-01 00:00:08',
 '1995-08-01 00:00:08',
 '1995-08-01 00:00:09']
```

Comment: I already have a list and tried this method, but it didn't work. It gave me an error at this point `dates = [datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S") for date in parsed_dates]`

Comment: Ok, can you tell which is the value it is trying to convert when the error is raised?

Perhaps use: `[print(date); datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S") for date in parsed_dates]` and post the last printed line

Comment: I'm getting error because I'm directly performing this on my list without splitting it using '\n' and probably there are some spaces in the end in my list.

Answer (score 1):

By using the following list

```
thislist = ["01/Aug/1995:00:00:01","01/Aug/1995:00:00:07","01/Aug/1995:00:00:08","01/Aug/1995:00:00:08","01/Aug/1995:00:00:08","01/Aug/1995:00:00:09"," 01/Aug/1995:00:00:09", "01//Jun/1996:10:10:10"]
```

with Try Except, one is able to know where exactly the error appears. More precisely,

```
import datetime
    
thislist = ["01/Aug/1995:00:00:01","01/Aug/1995:00:00:07","01/Aug/1995:00:00:08","01/Aug/1995:00:00:08","01/Aug/1995:00:00:08","01/Aug/1995:00:00:09"," 01/Aug/1995:00:00:09", "01//Jun/1996:10:10:10"]
    
for item in thislist:
    try:
        read = datetime.datetime.strptime(item,'%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
        print(read)
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError in: ")
        print(item)
```

Will print

[image: Initial result]

As you can see, the last two items in this adapted list (as in, grab yours and add two more items) are being caught by the except block.

While the code works fine in the initial items, in one of the added items there's a space in the beginning and in the other there's a two slashes instead of only one.

While your code would work fine if the items were all correctly formatted, this is not the case. To fix it, you'll have to deal with the reasons why it leads to the ValueError.

In this particular scenario, we'd need to ensure two things

1. There's no unnecessary spaces in the beginning of the string. This can be done with [strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method (we could have used lstrip() for this scenario but strip() will also remove unnecessary spaces in the end of the string)

   ```
    item.strip()
   ```
2. There's no two slashes separating. This can be done by replacing two slashes with one using [replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

   ```
    item.replace("//", "/")
   ```

So, the following code (notice that both item.strip and item.replace return a value)

```
import datetime
    
thislist = ["01/Aug/1995:00:00:01","01/Aug/1995:00:00:07","01/Aug/1995:00:00:08","01/Aug/1995:00:00:08","01/Aug/1995:00:00:08","01/Aug/1995:00:00:09"," 01/Aug/1995:00:00:09", "01//Jun/1996:10:10:10"]
    
for item in thislist:
    try:
        item = item.strip()
        item = item.replace("//", "/")
        read = datetime.datetime.strptime(item,'%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
        print(read)
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError in: ")
        print(item)
```

Will print no ValueError

[image: Final result]

Note that there's other possible scenarios you'd have to deal with specifically but this gives you an idea of how to do it.